# Transform the input of the MFCCs Spectogram for a CNN (Audio Recognition)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition

I have a dataset of audios, and I have transformed these audios intro MFCCs plot like this one:

[image]

**Now i want to feed my Neural network**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl

cnn_model = tfk.Sequential(name='CNN_model')
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 225, kernel_size= 11, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(4500,9000, 3)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.GRU(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, implementation=0)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Softmax())
cnn_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])

cnn_model.summary()
```

I use a Conv1D because is the used layer in this kind of NN. But I don't know how to make the data transformation from **image, to the input of the CNN**. I have tried several transformations by my own, but just it didn't work.

As you can see in the picture below, i need to feed the first layer that is a `Conv1D` but i can't because the shape of my image is `(4500, 9000, 3)`. So basically, **what i want to do, is transform this image in an input** for a `Conv1D` in the same way that in the image below.

[image]

This image represent 1 audio passed to the NN.

Obviously, when I pass one image with this shape to a `Conv1D` layer, I have a `ValueError` `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 4500, 9000, 3]`

**I pass my image into greyscale**, but is not the method and I lost a valuable information.

Comment: What does your image mean? Is anything in that image "time"?

Comment: Yes @DanielMöller the first image, the x axis is time. so you have to pass a different parts of the image (sencond image) and each part represent time.

Comment: Hmm.... so what does Y mean?

Comment: And what does the color mean?

Comment: @RubialesAlberto, how did you end up with an image with channels in the first place? The output of MFCC is (mfcc components, sequence_length). So where did the 3rd dimension come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like you are not looking at this as a typical speech recognition problem. Because I find several strange choices in your approach.

## Problems I noted

### The output shape of the MFCC operation.

If you look at [librosa.feature.mfcc](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html), this is what it says,

> Returns: M:np.ndarray [shape=(n_mfcc, t)]

So as you can see, there are no channels here. There's the input dimension (`n_mfcc`) and time dimension (`t`). Therefore, you should be directly able to use `Conv1D` without any preprocessing.

### Dropout before SoftMax

This is what the tail of your algorithm look like,

```
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Softmax())
```

Personally, I haven't used people using dropout on the last layer. So I would get rid of that. Because dropout randomly switches of neurons. But you want all your output nodes on at any time.

### The loss function

Usually, [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionist_temporal_classification) is what is used to optimize speech recognition models. I (personally) haven't seen anybody using `mae` as a loss for a speech model. Because, your input data and label data usually have mis-aligned time dimensions. This means, there not always a label corresponding to each time step of the prediction. And that's where CTC loss shines. That's probably what you want to use for this model (unless you are 100% certain that there is a label for each an every single prediction and they are perfectly aligned).

Having said this, the loss depends on the problem you're solving. But I will include an example of how to use this loss for this problem.

## A working example

### The dataset

To show a working example, I'm going to use the [this](https://github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset) speech dataset. I chose this because, I can get a good result quickly due to the simplicity of the problem.

- Input: An audio
- Output: A label 0-9

### MFCC transformation

Then you can perform MFCC on the audio files, and you will get the following heatmap. So as I said before, this will be a 2D matrix `(n_mfcc, timesteps)` sized array. With the batch dimension it becomes, `(batch size, n_mfcc, timesteps)`.

[image]

Here's how you can visualize the above. Here, y is an audio loaded via `librosa.core.load()` function.

```
y = audios[aid][1][0]
sr = audios[aid][1][1]
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20)
print(mfcc.shape)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc, x_axis='time')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('MFCC')
plt.tight_layout()
```

### Creating training/testing data

Next you can create your training and testing data. Here's what I create.

- train_data - A `(sample size, timesteps, n_mfcc)` size array
- train_labels = A `(sample size, timesteps, num_classes)` size array
- train_inp_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- train_seq_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- test_data - A `(sample size, timesteps, n_mfcc)` size array
- test_labels = A `(sample size, timesteps, num_classes+1)` size array
- test_inp_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- test_seq_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)

I am using the following mapping to convert chars to numbers

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
a_map = {} # map letter to number
rev_a_map = {} # map number to letter
for i, a in enumerate(alphabet):
  a_map[a] = i
  rev_a_map[i] = a

label_map = {0:'zero', 1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five', 6:'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9:'nine'}
```

Few things to note.

- Note that `mfcc` operation returns `(n_mfcc, time)`. You have to do an axis permutation to get it to `(time, n_mfcc)` format. So that the convolution happens on the time dimension.
- I also had to make sure that labels have exact same number of timesteps as the input (this is not necessary for the ctc_loss). But was a requirement enforced by keras model definition. This is done by adding spaces to the end of each sequence of chars.

### Defining the model

I have changed from a sequential API to a functional API, as I needed to included several input layers to make this work for `ctc_loss`. Furthermore, I got rid of that last dropout layer.

```
def ctc_loss(inp_lengths, seq_lengths):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        l = tf.reduce_mean(K.ctc_batch_cost(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), y_pred, inp_lengths, seq_lengths))        
        return l            
    return loss

K.clear_session()
inp = tfk.Input(shape=(10,50))
inp_len = tfk.Input(shape=(1))
seq_len = tfk.Input(shape=(1))
out = tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size= 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
out = tfkl.BatchNormalization()(out)
out = tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, implementation=0))(out)
out = tfkl.Dropout(0.2)(out)
out = tfkl.BatchNormalization()(out)
out = tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(27, activation='softmax'))(out)
cnn_model = tfk.models.Model(inputs=[inp, inp_len, seq_len], outputs=out)
cnn_model.compile(loss=ctc_loss(inp_lengths=inp_len , seq_lengths=seq_len), optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

### Training the model

Then you simply call,

```
cnn_model.fit([train_data, train_inp_lengths, train_seq_lengths], train_labels, batch_size=64, epochs=20)
```

which gave,

```
Train on 900 samples
Epoch 1/20
900/900 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/sample - loss: 11.4955 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0442
Epoch 2/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 4.1317 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0340
...
Epoch 19/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1162 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0275
Epoch 20/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1012 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0277
```

### Predicting with the model

```
y = cnn_model.predict([test_data, test_inp_lengths, test_seq_lengths])

n_ids = 5

for pred, true in zip(y[:n_ids,:,:], test_labels[:n_ids,:,:]):
  pred_ids = np.argmax(pred,axis=-1)
  true_ids = np.argmax(true, axis=-1)
  print('pred > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in pred_ids])
  print('true > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in true_ids])
```

this gives,

```
pred >  ['e', ' ', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'h', ' ', ' ', 't']
true >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['o', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
true >  ['o', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['s', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'v', 'e']
true >  ['s', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['z', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'r', 'o', ' ']
true >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['n', ' ', ' ', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ']
true >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

To get rid of repeating letters and spaces in between, use `ctc_decode` function as follows.

```
y = cnn_model.predict([test_data, test_inp_lengths, test_seq_lengths])

sess = K.get_session()
pred = sess.run(tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(y, test_inp_lengths[:,0]))

rev_a_map[-1] = '-'

for pred, true in zip(pred[0][0][:n_ids,:], test_labels[:n_ids,:,:]):
  print(pred.shape)  
  true_ids = np.argmax(true, axis=-1)
  print('pred > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in pred])
  print('true > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in true_ids])
```

which gave,

```
pred >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't']
true >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['o', 'n', 'e', '-', '-']
true >  ['o', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['s', 'e', 'i', 'v', 'n']
true >  ['s', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', '-']
true >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', '-']
true >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

- Note that I have added a new label `-1`. This is something added to represent any blanks by the `ctc_decode` function.

Comment: Thank you, but is not what i'm looking for. I'm trying to pass the plot of the MFCCs, not the MFCCs features. I saw this in an example of Udacity Nanodegree program, they use their own functions to do it, and it's imposible for me to replicate, so I'm trying to do it by my own.  However your answer is exceptional and there are a lot of knowledge that can't be wasted so I opened another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455752/how-to-train-a-nn-for-speech-recognition-with-mfccs-features). If you think that I'm wrong please tell me, Because you have more knowledge than me!

Comment: So you can just, copy your answerd and I will accept it! I think is important for the community. :)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto, yup posted my answer. This is an interesting problem you are trying to tackle. Are you then happy with the answers provided by others or still looking for better ways to improve performance? If so, I got a few questions. (1) would you be happy for a solution that solves the problem while using the plot as an input and produce good mae for this dataset? (2) Do you need to use the model as it is or do you agree that the issues I pointed out are in fact issues? (3) Can you share some resources to get a better idea of what they do in the Udacity program so we can replicate this.

Comment: I'm trying the Danniel Moler options, but I don't have more time today because i had a lot of work (are 11.30 PM in Spain). So I couldn't test all options. But of course I'm happy to recive help. (1)Absolutly yes, that's what's I'm looking for. (2) Yes I'm agree with them! I don't know why in the course they didn't talk me about ctc loss function, after your post i have read a few papers and it works!! 1/2

Comment: (3) Yes you can see this [Github repo](https://github.com/lucko515/speech-recognition-neural-network) the main document for the project is "vui_notebook-ipynb" and you can see others .py files where they do a lot of functions. "utils.py", "train_utils.py", and "sample_models.py" are the main files.  I have tried to do the second model (CNN+ RNN + Timedistributed Dense) and the "final model" (the final part of the notebook) with any succes. Even I become crazy and I have tried to change the model and it's not exactly the same that in the Notebook (after 3 weeks trying to do it). 2/2

Answer (score 3):

I think you can convert the image into grayscale, but you risk losing a lot of valuable data.

The best possible approach is to reshape the MFCC spectogram. `img.reshape(4500, 3 * 9000)`

**Example**

```py
# Sample data
>>> a
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 2, 3)

# Reshaping data
>>> a.reshape(2, -1)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])

# Or
>>> a.reshape(2, 6)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: I have done, but yes as you said I lost valuable information :(.

Answer (score 1):

If you say X is time, thus considering the shape as `(examples, time_steps, frequency_bins, img_channels)`, there are things you can try.

### Option 1

The most obvious was mentioned in @skillsmuggler answer. Everything that is not time is feature, so:

```
#if in the model:
x_train = original_x_train
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Reshape((4500, 27000), input_shape=(4500,9000,3))) #first layer


#if directly in the data:
x_train = original_x_train.reshape((-1, 4500, 27000))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 225, kernel_size= 11, padding='same', 
                          activation='relu', input_shape=(4500,9000, 3))) #original first layer
```

### Option 2

But there are more possibilities. I don't know what the MFCC is, but I suspect it's made of:

- x = time steps
- y = frequency bins
- color = intensity

If that is true, the first thing is to get the original value of the intensity instead of a 3-channel pixel value. It would be way easier for a network to get the idea of a continuous value than 3 channels varying in a more complex way to represent the same thing (those colors are only for our human eyes, but they're considerably more complex mathematically)

If you can access the original values instead of colors, then you can have as **option 2** inputs like `(examples, time_steps, frequency_bins)` and that is it, no image color channels. Less inputs, better represented information. The values in this case are "intensity".

```
print(x_train.shape) #-> (examples, 4500, 9000)
```

Then your model would need no change.

### Option 3

Now, if you say you are losing information with the above methods, then you could try many other fancy things, and the first I can think of is to first convolve the frequency dimension, pool or collapse it somehow, and then start processing the time dimension.

Something like this two part model.

**Part 1:** convolving and collapsing the frequency.

```
input_channels = 1 or 3 #preferrably 1, following option 2, 
                        #but it's possible to use the 3 channel images too (less optimal)

cnn_model = tfk.Sequential(name='CNN_model')
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(
                  Conv1D(filters, size, activation=...), 
                  input_shape=(4500,9000,input_channels))) 

#shapes will be all in the type (examples, 4500, decreasing_freq_size, increasing_channels)
#make a time distributed conv model in the VGG style until you collapse the last channel dimension
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(Conv1D(...)))
...
cnn_model.add(tfkl.MaxPooling1D())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(Conv1D(...)))
...
cnn_model.add(tfkl.MaxPooling1D())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(Conv1D(...)))
...

#when the 9000 has been reduced a lot
import tf.keras.backend as K
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=2))) 
    #the line above is equivalent to the following, but seems more efficient
    #cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling1D())) 

#new shape style: (examples, 4500, increased_channels) 
#no need for a huge number of channels, maybe around 100?
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dense(units=around_100)) #Dense is equal to TimeDistributed(Dense)
```

Now that you transformed shapes like `(examples, 4500, 9000, ch_1_or_3)` into shapes like `(examples, 4500, features_around_100)`, you can go to the second part which is your original model.

**Part 2:** continue with your original model.

```
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 225, kernel_size= 11, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Bidirectional(
                  tfkl.GRU(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, implementation=0)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Softmax())
cnn_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

### Option 4

Can be used with option 3. 
Since the frequency dimension is probably linearly increasing vertically and since convolutions don't see the dimension they're convolving as a whole, you could add a channel with the normalized frequency value (not intensity, but actual frequency) and see if it adds good information.

So, as an example, considering option 2 with shape `(examples, 4500, 9000, channels_1_or_3)`. Choose one:

**In the input data:**

```
freq_channel = (numpy.arange(9000) / 9000) - 0.5 #shape (9000,)
freq_channel = numpy.stack([freq_channel] * 4500, axis=0) #shape (4500,9000)
freq_channel = numpy.stach([freq_channel] * examples, axis=0) #shape (examples, 4500, 9000)
freq_channel = freq_channel.reshape((-1, 4500, 9000, 1))
new_x_train = numpy.concatenate([original_x_train, freq_channel], axis=-1))
```

**In the model:**

```
import tf.keras.backend as K
def add_freq_channel(x):
    shape = K.shape(x) #(examples, 4500, 9000, channels)
    shape = K.concatenate([shape[:-1], K.constant([1])]) #(examples, 4500, 9000, 1)

    freq_channel = (K.arange(9000) / 9000) - 0.5 #shape (9000,)
    freq_channel = K.reshape(freq_channel, (1, 1, 9000, 1))
    freq_channel = freq_channel * K.ones(shape)

    return K.concatenate([x, freq_channel], axis=-1)

cnn_model.add(tfkl.Lambda(add_freq_channel, input_shape=(4500,9000,channels)))
```

You can maybe (not sure if it would bring improvements), expand this idea also for the time dimension. Add an additional channel following the same process above, but focusing on the X axis, with size 4500. In this case you can use it with any other other option.

### General suggestions for your model

- I'm not sure how `GRU` works, but since it's recurrent, maybe it's a better idea to stick with `activation = 'tanh'` for this layer. I've read somewhere, but can't remember where, that 'tanh' activations are better at least for LSTM layers. Maybe because of possible explosions due to recurrent calculations. (Of course you may test this and come to a better conclusion)
- `tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20))` is equal to just `tfkl.Dense(20)` in Keras. You can avoid adding the `TimeDistributed` overhead here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm working on it!