# How to train a NN for speech recognition with MFCCs features

Tags: python

I have a audio Database and I'm using Librosa and MFCCs algorithm to do Speech recognition. I have 20 features output from MFCC algorithm but now i don't know how to pass this as an input of the algorithm. So my model is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl

cnn_model = tfk.Sequential(name='CNN_model')
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 225, kernel_size= 11, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(4500,9000, 3)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.GRU(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, implementation=0)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.BatchNormalization())
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Softmax())
cnn_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])

cnn_model.summary()
```

and the input is

```
In: X_train_reshape[0].shape
Out: (1500, 20)
```

I have try a lot of things, but I always have a dimension error.
`ValueError  Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 256, 256, 3)`

Comment: The error message is not compatible with the shape of `X_train_reshape`. Something is not right in the question.

Comment: Which one is time? 1500 or 20? The time dimension should be the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you are not looking at this as a typical speech recognition problem. Because I find several strange choices in your approach.

## Problems I noted

### Dropout before SoftMax

This is what the tail of your algorithm look like,

```
cnn_model.add(tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(20)))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Dropout(0.2))
cnn_model.add(tfkl.Softmax())
```

Personally, I haven't used people using dropout on the last layer. So I would get rid of that. Because dropout randomly switches of neurons. But you want all your output nodes on at any time.

### The loss function

Usually, [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionist_temporal_classification) is what is used to optimize speech recognition models. I (personally) haven't seen anybody using `mae` as a loss for a speech model. Because, your input data and label data usually have mis-aligned time dimensions. This means, there not always a label corresponding to each time step of the prediction. And that's where CTC loss shines. That's probably what you want to use for this model (unless you are 100% certain that there is a label for each an every single prediction and they are perfectly aligned).

Having said this, the loss depends on the problem you're solving. But I will include an example of how to use this loss for this problem.

## A working example

### The dataset

To show a working example, I'm going to use the [this](https://github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset) speech dataset. I chose this because, I can get a good result quickly due to the simplicity of the problem.

- Input: An audio
- Output: A label 0-9

### MFCC transformation

Then you can perform MFCC on the audio files, and you will get the following heatmap. So as I said before, this will be a 2D matrix `(n_mfcc, timesteps)` sized array. With the batch dimension it becomes, `(batch size, n_mfcc, timesteps)`.

[image]

Here's how you can visualize the above. Here, y is an audio loaded via `librosa.core.load()` function.

```
y = audios[aid][1][0]
sr = audios[aid][1][1]
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20)
print(mfcc.shape)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc, x_axis='time')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('MFCC')
plt.tight_layout()
```

### Creating training/testing data

Next you can create your training and testing data. Here's what I create.

- train_data - A `(sample size, timesteps, n_mfcc)` size array
- train_labels = A `(sample size, timesteps, num_classes)` size array
- train_inp_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- train_seq_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- test_data - A `(sample size, timesteps, n_mfcc)` size array
- test_labels = A `(sample size, timesteps, num_classes+1)` size array
- test_inp_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)
- test_seq_lengths - A `(sample size,`)` size array (for CTC loss)

I am using the following mapping to convert chars to numbers

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
a_map = {} # map letter to number
rev_a_map = {} # map number to letter
for i, a in enumerate(alphabet):
  a_map[a] = i
  rev_a_map[i] = a

label_map = {0:'zero', 1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five', 6:'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9:'nine'}
```

Few things to note.

- Note that `mfcc` operation returns `(n_mfcc, time)`. You have to do an axis permutation to get it to `(time, n_mfcc)` format. So that the convolution happens on the time dimension.
- I also had to make sure that labels have exact same number of timesteps as the input (this is not necessary for the ctc_loss). But was a requirement enforced by keras model definition. This is done by adding spaces to the end of each sequence of chars.

### Defining the model

I have changed from a sequential API to a functional API, as I needed to included several input layers to make this work for `ctc_loss`. Furthermore, I got rid of that last dropout layer.

```
def ctc_loss(inp_lengths, seq_lengths):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        l = tf.reduce_mean(K.ctc_batch_cost(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), y_pred, inp_lengths, seq_lengths))        
        return l            
    return loss

K.clear_session()
inp = tfk.Input(shape=(10,50))
inp_len = tfk.Input(shape=(1))
seq_len = tfk.Input(shape=(1))
out = tfkl.Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size= 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
out = tfkl.BatchNormalization()(out)
out = tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, implementation=0))(out)
out = tfkl.Dropout(0.2)(out)
out = tfkl.BatchNormalization()(out)
out = tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.Dense(27, activation='softmax'))(out)
cnn_model = tfk.models.Model(inputs=[inp, inp_len, seq_len], outputs=out)
cnn_model.compile(loss=ctc_loss(inp_lengths=inp_len , seq_lengths=seq_len), optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

### Training the model

Then you simply call,

```
cnn_model.fit([train_data, train_inp_lengths, train_seq_lengths], train_labels, batch_size=64, epochs=20)
```

which gave,

```
Train on 900 samples
Epoch 1/20
900/900 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/sample - loss: 11.4955 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0442
Epoch 2/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 4.1317 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0340
...
Epoch 19/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1162 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0275
Epoch 20/20
900/900 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1012 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0277
```

### Predicting with the model

```
y = cnn_model.predict([test_data, test_inp_lengths, test_seq_lengths])

n_ids = 5

for pred, true in zip(y[:n_ids,:,:], test_labels[:n_ids,:,:]):
  pred_ids = np.argmax(pred,axis=-1)
  true_ids = np.argmax(true, axis=-1)
  print('pred > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in pred_ids])
  print('true > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in true_ids])
```

this gives,

```
pred >  ['e', ' ', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'h', ' ', ' ', 't']
true >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['o', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
true >  ['o', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['s', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'v', 'e']
true >  ['s', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['z', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'r', 'o', ' ']
true >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['n', ' ', ' ', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ']
true >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

To get rid of repeating letters and spaces in between, use `ctc_decode` function as follows.

```
y = cnn_model.predict([test_data, test_inp_lengths, test_seq_lengths])

sess = K.get_session()
pred = sess.run(tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(y, test_inp_lengths[:,0]))

rev_a_map[-1] = '-'

for pred, true in zip(pred[0][0][:n_ids,:], test_labels[:n_ids,:,:]):
  print(pred.shape)  
  true_ids = np.argmax(true, axis=-1)
  print('pred > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in pred])
  print('true > ',[rev_a_map[tid] for tid in true_ids])
```

which gave,

```
pred >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't']
true >  ['e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['o', 'n', 'e', '-', '-']
true >  ['o', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['s', 'e', 'i', 'v', 'n']
true >  ['s', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', '-']
true >  ['z', 'e', 'r', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

pred >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', '-']
true >  ['n', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

- Note that I have added a new label `-1`. This is something added to represent any blanks by the `ctc_decode` function.